# I want to be able to have a daily task run showing the times users log on and off

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, csv, group-policy

**GOAL:**

I want to be able to have a daily task run showing the times users log on and off

**ENVIRONMENT:**

Windows 2008R2 domain

**ACTIONS SO FAR:**

I have enabled Account Auditing via:

- start -> administrator tools -> group policy management
- Forest -> Domains -> Default Domain Policy
- right-click -> edit
- Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Audit Policy
- double-click **Audit Account Logon Events**

**RESULTS:**

I logged off and on and the events are now being entered into the Security Log.
If I open the Event Viewer and look at the entries, I can see the Account Name under the New Logon section of the General tab.

**MY PROBLEM:**

I need to be able to export the logons and logoffs to a csv file, on a daily basis.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -instanceID 4624,4634 -after ((get-date).addDays(-1)) | Export-Csv D:\ADReports\test.csv
```

This creates a CSV file but the **New Logon** info is not included.  Obviously the user account info is there because I see it in the eventID in Event Viewer.

Have I turned on the wrong auditing?  My PowerShell scripting knowledge is basic.
Can someone please assist me in this elusive (to me) script?

Comment: @Heptite  Thank you for the prompt reply.  I am able to get a CSV file.  I could before.  The problem is the CSV file is missing data.  All of the information is in the CSV **except** the username.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/je56frnietc0znq/test.csv  The username is in the Event Viewer (see attached screen shot) https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xwb6ebvm59a4pq/event-viewer.JPG.  I do not know why I cannot export the username field.  Please help.

Comment: All I did was edit your post to fix it up a bit, which isn't a reply. You might want to edit your post yourself and put the extra information from your comment directly into your question.